# PYTHON error in SQL syntax while writing json to MYSQL database

Tags: python, sql, json

I want to receive json data from MQTT and store it in my database.

When am executing my code am receiving this error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1
```

There is my code :

```
import mysql.connector
import json

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="***",
  passwd="***",
  database="database"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

def DATA_REPARTITION(Topic, jsonData):
 if Topic == "test":
    #print ("Start")
    INSERT_DEBIT(jsonData)




def INSERT_DEBIT(jsonData):
  #Read json from MQTT
  print("Start read data to insert") 
  json_Dict = json.loads(jsonData)
  debit = json_Dict['debit']

 #Insert into DB Table
  sql = ("INSERT INTO debit (data_debit) VALUES (%s)")
  val=(debit)

  mycursor.execute(sql,val)

  mydb.commit()

  print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")

  mycursor.close()
  mydb.close()
```

Thanks for your help, am working on this problem for the last 2 days.

Comment: Like the error log of the SQL database?

Comment: @Denziloe This looks like a mistake in trying to parameterize the query which totally makes it a Python-related question.

Comment: Thanks i change my sql to :      sql = ("INSERT INTO debit (data_debit) VALUES (%s)"%(debit)).   It working now thanks.   Why this is dangerous? It's good like this?

Comment: I print the data I try to send to the database and this is exactly the data I want to send

Comment: @VincentCoderre [xkcd demonstrates why this is dangerous](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Why are you giving me this link?

Comment: You should never plug in user inputs directly into SQL commands because it allows SQL injection attacks to happen, and you could end up allowing the user to run SQL commands on your database. The link shows an SQL injection attack where the user is able to delete a table in the database.

Comment: I see now, thanks. I will find a way to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've written your parameterized query properly for MySQL:

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO debit (data_debit) VALUES (%s)")
```

The problem is that you're passing in the arguments wrong:

```
val=(debit)

mycursor.execute(sql,val)
```

The parentheses don't make `debit` into a tuple of 1 value. They don't do anything at all; `val` is just the same value as `debit`.

But `execute` wants a sequence of separate values, not 1 value.

---

To fix this, you need to add a comma. Commas are what create tuples in Python:

```
val = debit,
```

---

If you're wondering why this raises a SQL error, instead of a Python error about `val` not being iterable… Most likely, `val` is a string. And strings *are* iterable. They just iterate their characters. If `val` is, say, `'$100'`, then you're passing the arguments `'$'`, `'1'`, `'0'`, and `'0'`, to fit a parameterized query with only one parameter.